# Multiprocessing in Java Using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, multiprocessing, processbuilder

I working on a project that needs to run a shell file in MAC OS for many times. The shell file writes the result of each run on a separate log file. To speed up the process I have to use all the available cores in our machine. I tried to do this using BuildProcess in Java. It works fine for few seconds but the processes stop after few seconds. Each process takes about 18 hours when running on single core machine. For instance if run the followings it starts two processes and keeps them running for about 10 seconds but then they will be killed with no error!

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "runFS.sh")
Process p1 = pb1.start()

ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "runFS.sh")
Process p2 = pb2.start();
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the script requires no input from the user? What about the log files? What do they say? Can you control stdout/stderr and redirect them where you want instead?

Comment: Note that the stdin, stdout, and stdErr of processes created by a ProcessBuilder are not connected to the console.  If you want to see the output of those processes (i.e. their error messages) you will have to use Process#getErrorStream/getInputStream.

Comment: The output of the program is save in log files. This has been handled in the runFS.sh. I just simple want to run this file with different parameters on different CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

If your example code is anything to go by, you're lacking `p1.waitFor()` and `p2.waitFor()` to actually keep the main process alive while the child processes are running. So when your JVM shuts down, it kills also the processes you started.

Comment: I tried using waitFor(), but then it doesn't make several processes to run several instances of runFS.sh simultaneously. It runs each instance one after each other.

Comment: Is there any other way to keep the main process alive while the subprocesses are still running?

Comment: Oneway to keep the main alive is asking for an input from user. Like using `int tmp = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();` But I need more structural way to do this.

Comment: @Arash you need to keep your main process doing something. If you don't use waitFor(), you'll have to do something else. Also, if you call waitFor() after you've started both the processes, they will run at the same time.